# How to rename a file, only removing the first instance of the character

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a large list of names and certain filed tied to each name such as:
`First_Last_DOB_RT_...` and so on. What I want to do is add a `-x` to the beginning of the filename. However, let's say the first and last name was: Susy_Sample. In this case simply using the

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "S","-x S"}
```

will end up converting each instance of `S` to `-x S` when I only want the beginning of the file to start with `-x`. How would can I do that?

Comment: Yeahh... I just realized how easy it was after I posted that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the beginning of the string with `-x`:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^', '-x ' }
```

Another option is to concatenate `-x` with the name as @PetSerAl suggested:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName { '-x ' + $_.Name }
```